# Using Splunk Dashboard how to create a filter for each column of a table

Tags: splunk

I have a table that I saved as a report and created a dashboard that displays the table.
I want to add inputs for each field on the table to be able to filter the table data.
This is the table
[image]

I added a text box as the first input
[image]

How do I link the text box that has a token called **purchCostReferenceToken** to the purchCostReference column on the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Strictly speaking, the input and the table are not related.  The input controls the *search* and the table is one way to represent the results of the search.

To control the search, use the input token in it.  Use dollar signs to denote the token.  For example,

```
index=foo purchCostReference=$purchCostReferenceToken$ | ...
```

You will need a default value for the token to make this work when no input is provided.  Usually, that value is `*`.